# python, move all files from 3rd,4th , 5th to 2nd level of directory tree

Tags: python, linux

I know we have `os.walk` but I can't figure out how to create this.

Lets say I have the following folder structure on a ubuntu linux box:

```
Maindir (as root called by script)
 +- subdir-one
 |   +-subdir-two
 |     +-file
 |     +-another file
 |     +-subdir-three
 |       +-file3
 |       +-file4
 |       +-subdir-four
 |         +- file5
 |         +- file6
 +- subdir-two
 +- subdir-three
 |   +-sub-subdir-two
 |     +-file
 |     +-another file
 |     +-subdir-three
 |       +-file3
 |       +-file4
 |       +-subdir-four
 |         +-file5
 |         +-file6
 +-subdir-four
   +-subdir-two
     +-file
     +-another file
     +-subdir-three
       +-file3
       +-file4
       +-subdir-four
         +-file5
         +-file6
```

I want to move all files from the subdir's to the subdirs on level 2, not to the root level.

Take subdir-one as example: Move all files in subdir-four to subdir-one (in this case file5 and file6), Move all files from subdir-three to subdir-one (in this case file3 and file4)

Subdir-two has no other subdirs so can be skipped by the script.

Subdir-three: move all files from sub-subdir-two, subdir-three and subdir-four to subdir-three.

I think you get the point. No problem if files are overwritten, if they have the same name they are duplicates anyway, one reason for running this cleanup script.

When all files are moved from the subdir's it means the subdir's will be empty so I also want to remove the empty sub-dirs.

Update on 14-1-2012: This is the changed code given from jcollado but still not working. Btw I forgot to mention that I also need to filter some directory names. These directory names need to be excluded from being processed when found within the directory tree..

The code I slightly changed:

```
    import os, sys

    def main():

    try:
     main_dir = sys.argv[1]
     print main_dir
     # Get a list of all subdirectories of main_dir
     subdirs = filter(os.path.isdir,
             [os.path.join(main_dir, path)
              for path in os.listdir(main_dir)])
print subdirs
# For all subdirectories,
# collect all files and all subdirectories recursively

for subdir in subdirs:
 files_to_move = []
 subdirs_to_remove = []
 for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(subdir):
  files_to_move.extend([os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                        for filename in filenames])
  subdirs_to_remove.extend([os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
                        for dirname in dirnames])

                            # To move files, just rename them replacing the original directory
                            # with the target directory (subdir in this case)
print files_to_move
print subdirs_to_remove
for filename in files_to_move:
                              source = filename
                              destination = os.path.join(subdir, os.path.basename(filename))
                              print 'Destination ='+destination

                              if source != destination:
                                   os.rename(source, destination)
                              else:
                                print 'Rename cancelled, source and destination were the same'


                                  # Reverse subdirectories order to remove them
                                  # starting from the lower level in the tree hierarchy
                              subdirs_to_remove.reverse()

                                      # Remove subdirectories
for dirname in subdirs_to_remove:
                                        #os.rmdir(dirname)
                                        print dirname

except ValueError:
  print 'Please supply the path name on the command line'

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, perhaps try to split your program into three levels of independent walks. One which goes down two steps in the hierarchy, one that moves all files below to the "root" (which is now where you left of in the previous step) and one step that erases all empty dirs recursively.

Comment: Does it have to be in Python, or could you use a shell command? `for d in */; do find  "$d" -depth -mindepth 2 -type f -path '*/*/*/*' -exec mv {} "$d" \; -o -type d -empty -delete; done`

Comment: Hi jcollado. The code you send me is not complete. It is not working. Only the last dir in the array is being processed. I try to change your code with no luck. I put the changed code in answer below, but it is not working...

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your answer. I realy like to have this answered in python. shell could be possible but your solution is not dynamic? What happens if we have a directory tree 10 levels deep??

Answer (score 2):

I'd something as follows:

```
import os

main_dir = 'main'

# Get a list of all subdirectories of main_dir
subdirs = filter(os.path.isdir,
                 [os.path.join(main_dir, path)
                  for path in os.listdir(main_dir)])

# For all subdirectories,
# collect all files and all subdirectories recursively
for subdir in subdirs:
  files_to_move = []
  subdirs_to_remove = []
  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(subdir):
    files_to_move.extend([os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                          for filename in filenames])
    subdirs_to_remove.extend([os.path.join(dirpath, dirname)
                              for dirname in dirnames])

  # To move files, just rename them replacing the original directory
  # with the target directory (subdir in this case)
  for filename in files_to_move:
    source = filename
    destination = os.path.join(subdir, os.path.basename(filename))
    os.rename(source, destination)

  # Reverse subdirectories order to remove them
  # starting from the lower level in the tree hierarchy
  subdirs_to_remove.reverse()

  # Remove subdirectories
  for dirname in subdirs_to_remove:
    os.rmdir(dirname)
```

Note: You can turn this into a function just using `main_dir` as a parameter.